# Xcode 8 and Google maps error with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, cocoa-touch, swift3

I am using Google maps in my project which was working fine while using Xcode 7.3 but recently i have updated my XCode to 8th version so now while i am trying to open the project a popup appears asking me to convert the project to Swift 3.0 version and when convert it, the project generates lots of errors in all the .swift file.
i am using cocoapods for Google Maps. here are the pods i am using :

```
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

can anyone tell me why the errors appear and how to resolve those errors, or are there any other pods which support swift 3.0 version.

Comment: I am facing the same situation. I did migrate to Swift 2.3 waiting for all pods to be in Swift 3

Comment: @bobby even 2.3 conversion doesnt seems to be working for me can you please tell me what changes you have made.

Comment: None en GoogleMaps code. When the migration tool did appear, I choose Swift 2.3, and I checked the Google Maps Pod in the file list.

I had to update a bit of my own code and then, everything was working

Comment: Even though Xcode says it convert to swift 3, there are places where it doesn't, so i converted it myself. The difficulties I faced while converting  were I had to reconnect all the buttons in the interface and the function names(eg:tableview delegates and datasources) are changed and the compiler doesn't show any error, it shows only a warning and when I build the project the functions doesn't execute until i changed its name. Can you specify one or two errors you have?

Comment: faced same issue using Xcode8, swift3. run pod update fixed the issue and install latest versions:  Installing GoogleMaps 2.1.0 (was 1.13.2)
Installing GooglePlaces 2.1.0 (was 1.0.4)